# Converter string em XML

Tags: c#

Considerem a tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No code behind, eu não consigo converter uma string em um xml

```
  modCamadaOperacao objModCamada = new modCamadaOperacao();
  objModCamada.idCamadaOperacao = idCamada; 
  objModCamada.xmlCamadaOperacao = serializer.Xml; // XML_CAMADA_OPERACAO
```

No caso a string é o `serializer.Xml`

o erro que retorna é:

> Cannot implicity convert type string to system.Xml.XmlDocument

Comment: Quem ta negativando por favor se manifeste, pois nao vejo motivos para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tente usar esta conversão.**

```
public static class Serializa
{
    public static string SerializaParaString<T>(this T valor)
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(valor.GetType());
        StringWriter retorno = new StringWriter();
        xml.Serialize(retorno, valor);
        return retorno.ToString();
    }

    public static object DeserializaParaObjeto(string valor, Type tipo)
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(tipo);
        var valorSerealizado = new StringReader(valor);
        return xml.Deserialize(valorSerealizado);
    }
}
```

**Chamada dos métodos de conversão:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stringParaSerializar = "Frase Qualquer";

        var valor = Serializa.SerializaParaString(stringParaSerializar);

        Console.WriteLine(valor);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<string>Frase Qualquer</string>
```

> Mais informações sobre serializar e deserializar objetos XML para string: [C# -  Serializando Objetos para String e vice-versa](http://www.macoratti.net/16/02/c_serobj1.htm)